# MS Access VBA AddItem when string contains semi-colons

Tags: ms-access, vba, escaping

To add items to a multi column listbox, using AddItem(), I understood that the text for each column should be delimited with a semicolon.

But what happens if the text to go in one of the columns already contains a semicolon? Is there a way to escape it so that AddItem() treats it literally? Currently the text gets spread over two columns.

I'm using VBA in MS Access 2003. The relevant line of code looks like this:
  lstResults.AddItem (rstItems("[ItemID]") & ";" & rstItems("[Description]"))
and rstItems("[Description]") itself contains a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes:

```
 """" & rstItems("[Description]")) & """"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Things have improved - it has stopped wrapping onto columns on the next line, but text in the last column is now truncated at the semicolon. Also having the same problem with quote marks in the data.

Comment: You know you could avoid these problems by setting the rowsource type to table/query and the rowsource to an sql string, eg : `SELECT ItemID, Description From Table` ?

Comment: I am not experiencing truncation in my test. Quotes (") should be replaced with two quotes : `Replace(rs!Description,"""","""""")`